# Logo overflow on navbar (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am really new to bootstrap, and I got kind of frustrated with it.
I am trying to build a responsive website, and I need my logo to overflow navbar. I did it in html and css(Without using bootstrap), but it is not responsive.
This is what I want to do with bootstrap but I keep failing miserably.
http://prntscr.com/5tifol
This is html/css code:

```
`<body>
<div id="motodiv">
<div id="text1" style="display:none;">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</div>
<div id="text2" style="display:none;">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTT</div>
</div>
<div id="logo"><img id="logoimg" src="logo.png"></div>`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yn7o2neb/
And this is what I did with bootstrap
http://prntscr.com/5tifrp
This is bootstrap code:  `

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                        <a class="brand" href="index.html"> <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive clearfix logo"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oc5vgha4/
Any help is welcome. Also, the navbar is resizing when I try to resize image.

Comment: Since there is no code here to see what you have tried, can you tell us if you have tried css positioning?

Comment: I have tried css positioning, but it isn't responsive. I added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS on the `.navbar-brand` class

```
.navbar-brand {                
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50px;        
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

You can adjust the padding and even the positioning as you see fit. 
You can see my example on http://jsfiddle.net/0hmrd1b8/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear this helps you. Mind up-voting my answer as the answer that solved your problem? :) @DimitrijeMitic

Comment: If you click the check mark, that is what says that my answer solved your problem @DimitrijeMitic

Comment: I clicked! I'm new, I didn't know, thank you again :)

Comment: Not a problem :) @DimitrijeMitic